# Select the customers logged the last day since an determinated hour

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

I want to display prommatically the last customers loggin since yesterday from 21:00 .
I think i could get this data from

> Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
>
> Mage::getModel('log/customer')->loadByCustomer($custom);

But can't, and i was looking for other codes and didn't found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least i found the database log on log_customers
Using Mage_log then i get:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('log/visitor')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('log_customer'=>$collection->getTable('log/customer')),´main_table.´visitor_id´=log_customer.visitor_id´');
foreach($collection->getItems() as $custom) {
   print_r($custom->getData());
}
```

But i don't know why, there is only a few results in the database.